# how to create & encode a label file using sample images for tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

we are trying to detect special characters like + and - inside an image using tensorflow by extending the MNIST sample code ->  https://github.com/opensourcesblog/tensorflow-mnist

We have also been able to create a binary encoded file using our sample images needed for training the neural network by using the sample code -> https://github.com/jkarnows/idx-formatter

But we are not finding a  way how to create a label file for our images and then to create a binary encoded label file using the label file

Both of these files are very important for proceeding further .

Anybody having any idea is most welcome to share them with us

Answer (score 0):

The data is in gzip format, decoded with [extract_labels](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L90), each label on 8 bytes. You can use `numpy.getbuffer` to convert a `uint8` array back.

Alternatively, you can just create your own `extract_labels` which reads labels in whatever format you see fit.

Comment: we are able to create a label binary file but now we are struck up with the following issue :  1) 5 images of minus(-) & 5 images of plus(+) with 5 rows of 0 label followed by 5 rows of 1 label -> result the prediction is coming 0 for both plus and minus sample image . 2) 1 image of minus(-) & 1 image of plus(+) with 1 row of 0 label followed by 1 row of 1 label -> result the prediction is coming 0 for both plus and minus sample image